# Android - java.lang.NullPointerException when loading files for the second time

Tags: java, android, file-io, io

In my app I have to load data contained in different files in a folder. It works well the first time, but it forces closes the second time I want to load the files (after I have modified them)

```
01-07 14:55:51.034: W/dalvikvm(3650): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
01-07 14:55:51.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 14:55:51.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3650): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-07 14:55:51.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):     at com.hangin.around.Modele.<init>(Modele.java:27)
01-07 14:55:51.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):     at com.hangin.around.MainActivity$5.onClick(MainActivity.java:386)
01-07 14:55:51.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2506)
01-07 14:55:51.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9112)
01-07 14:55:51.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-07 14:55:51.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-07 14:55:51.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-07 14:55:51.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
01-07 14:55:51.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 14:55:51.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-07 14:55:51.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
01-07 14:55:51.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
01-07 14:55:51.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3650):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is where I load the code in MainActivity :

```
...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ...

                // Checking if storage is available
                String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

                if (storageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
                    // Listing the files contained in the folder
                    listFiles = listFiles(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "HanginAround" + File.separator + "modeles" ));

                    // Creating models
                    if (!(listFiles == null)){
                        listeModeles = new Modele[NB_MODELES];
                        for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length ; i++){
                            listeModeles[i] = new Modele(listFiles[i]); 
                        } // for
                    }// if (listFiles != 0)
                }// if (MEDIA_MOUNTED)
                else {
                    // If storage is unavailable, then show a popup indicating it's not available
                    ...
                }

                ...

            }
        });

        ...

    }

    public File[] listFiles(File directory) {
        // This function return all *.csv files contained in the folder specified in the parameters

        // Listing all files in the folder
        File[] list = directory.listFiles();
        ArrayList<File> arrayListOfFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

        if(!(list == null)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
            {
               if (list[i].isFile() && ( (list[i].getName().endsWith(".csv")) || (list[i].getName().endsWith(".CSV")) ) ) 
               {
                   Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity : " + list[i].getName());
                   arrayListOfFiles.add(list[i]);
                   NB_MODELES += 1;
               } // if ( *.csv )
            } // for ( i < list.length )
        } // if (!(list == null))

        if (NB_MODELES == 0){
            // Showing a popup indicating there's no models in the directory
            ...
        }
        else {
            File[] listOfFiles = new File[NB_MODELES];

            Iterator<File> it =  arrayListOfFiles.iterator();
            int i = 0;

            while (it.hasNext()){
                listOfFiles[i] = (File) it.next();
                i++;
            }

            return listOfFiles; 
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And here is my class Modele :

```
package com.hangin.around;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import android.util.Log;

public class Modele {

    private  String nom;

    private Queue<double[]> fifo = new LinkedList<double[]>();

    private File file ;
    private final static String TAG = "Modele";

    public Modele(File parFile)
    {
        file = parFile;
        // Cutting off the extention from the file name
        String strLine = file.getName();
        StringTokenizer string = new StringTokenizer(strLine, ".");
        nom = string.nextToken();

        // Reading the file
        try{
            // Open the file that is the first 
            // command line parameter
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
            // Get the object of DataInputStream
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            strLine = "";
            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                // Add each value into a table
                StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(strLine, ";");
                double values[] = new double[3];
                int i=0;

                while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    values[i]= Double.parseDouble(stringTokenizer.nextToken());                 
                    i++;        
                }
                // Adding the tab into the Queue
                fifo.add(values);               
            }

            // Close the input stream
            in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){// Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    // Class's getters and setters
    public void setNom(String parNom)
    {
        nom=parNom;
    }

    public void setFifo(Queue<double[]> parFifo)
    {
        fifo=parFifo;
    }

    public void setFile(File parFile)
    {
        file=parFile;
    }

    public String getNom()
    {
        return nom;     
    }

    public Queue<double[]> getFifo()
    {
        return fifo;        
    }

    public File getFile()
    {
        return file;        
    }

}
```

I can't see where the error comes from, can you help me ?
Thanks in advance ;)

**EDIT :**

Line 27 in Modele.java is

```
String strLine = file.getName();
```

And line 386 in MainActitivy.java is

```
listeModeles[i] = new Modele(listFiles[i]);
```

Comment: Which is line 27 in Modele.java?

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot that, sorry.

So line 27 in Modele.java is 
`String strLine = file.getName();`

And line 386 in MainActitivy.java is
`listeModeles[i] = new Modele(listFiles[i]);`

Comment: @BlackEco Somehow it can't find the name of the variable `file` in Modele.java. But I find it weird that is does work when you start it the first time, and not the second time. Aren't you deleting the file somehow when you start it the first time? That would be my guess

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you didn't reset NB_MODELES to 0 before re-reading the files and so you array of files is too big (with null at the end).

Please note that there are simple methods to create array from a list. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29).

Comment: It was exactly the source of the problem.
Silly me !

Comment: Thanks for the `toArray` tip, anyway ;)